# How to determine if a CheerioElement is a heading

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I would like to determine if a `CheerioElement` is of type heading. I can do this with html elements like so:

```js
const h = document.getElementById('h1');
const p = document.getElementById('p');

const isHeading = e => e instanceof HTMLHeadingElement

console.log(isHeading(h));
console.log(isHeading(p));
```

```html
<h1 id="h1">Heading</h1>
<p id="p">Paragraph</p>
```

But I can't find any documentation on how to extract an HTML element from Cheerio. I don't know whether this is possible - perhaps Cheerio doesn't construct elements ion the same way as accessing the actual DOM and as such it wouldn't be possible to use prototypes in this way.

Is it possible to determine if a CheerioElement is a heading?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.html()` with your cheerio element. It will return a string and for headings it will return `"Heading"`.

```
const $ = cheerio.load('<h1 id="h1">Heading</h1><p id="p">Paragraph</p>');
const h = $('h1');
const p = $('p');

const isHeading = e => e === 'Heading';

console.log(isHeading(h.html()));
console.log(isHeading(p.html()));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same as browser HTML elements (nodejs doesn't implement DOM), you can drop into parse5 which is the cheerio implementation of those:

```
const isHeading = el => !!el.tagName?.match(/^h\d/)

$('*').get().map(el => isHeading(el))
```